# Wrapping Longer Sentences Without Affecting the Content

Tags: php, html, css, twitter

I am designing a portfolio where I need to fetch the latest twitter post and share it on the website. The `font-size` of the tweet is set to `3.1em`. On the right of the latest tweet container would be the container that holds the blog posts by the concerned client.
Now when I tested the the page I found this problem

> When I posted a new tweet (with a URL in it) and refreshed the portfolio page the link contained in the tweet overlapped the blog post content on the right due to the large font size of the tweet being displayed.

If there is any possible way to wrap the link without making it senseless, I would love to know about it. I'm using PHP for the backend & HTML/CSS for the front end. Please feel free to ask any questions if you find the question confusing. Thanks.

Comment: @BoltClock I suppose removing the CSS3 tag was not a great idea because ultimately the answer was held in a CSS3 feature ;)

Comment: If your question isn't specifically about CSS3, there's no need to have that tag even if the answer provided uses a CSS3 feature. If you want, you can roll back the edit, I don't mind.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh it's completely ok. I was just kidding. You know more, at least than me, for you're the moderator. And after all, I've got my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.impressivewebs.com/word-wrap-css3/

Comment: Your answer appears to be a *stub*. Please [provide context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for the link you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `word-wrap:break-word;` CSS property.  Also make sure to specify the width, else it would not work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this time I give the points to @KaeVrens for the link that led me to appropriateness. It's `word-wrap:break-word`. :)

Comment: Oh yes, it's break-word. Thanks for the correction. I'll update my answer.